# Compile python wheel with SWIG for manylinux without linking to libpython

Tags: python, swig, pypi

I'm trying to dig a bit deeper into binary packages with python with the wheel format, and I thought I might try to give wheelifying [one of my dependencies](https://github.com/ElementsProject/libwally-core) as an exercise.

To maximize the reusability of the resulting package I want to build it using the [`manylinux`](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) containers, which compiles the binaries included in the package with the lowest common denominator that I'm likely to encounter. However I'm unsure how to avoid linking against a specific `libpython.so`. The [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/#libpythonx-y-so-1) describe this in a rather abstract way:

> Note that libpythonX.Y.so.1 is not on the list of libraries that a manylinux1 extension is allowed to link to. Explicitly linking to libpythonX.Y.so.1 is unnecessary in almost all cases: the way ELF linking works, extension modules that are loaded into the interpreter automatically get access to all of the interpreter's symbols, regardless of whether or not the extension itself is explicitly linked against libpython. Furthermore, explicit linking to libpython creates problems in the common configuration where Python is not built with --enable-shared. In particular, on Debian and Ubuntu systems, apt install pythonX.Y does not even install libpythonX.Y.so.1, meaning that any wheel that did depend on libpythonX.Y.so.1 could fail to import.

So I'm wondering, SWIG generates the python wrappers for the C functions, and obviously makes use of the `libpython` functions, so the linker will try to link in `libpython`, which `manylinux` doesn't provide. If I understand correctly I am supposed to somehow leave the references dangling/unlinked and the interpreter will provide those symbols at runtime when loading the shared library, but how am I supposed to compile this in the first place?